# asking for the user input in order to either rerun the program or exit

Tags: c++

I am creating a program where basically the user is asked for three values and the program will take in those values and then input them into the quadratic formula. I got the quadratic formula and all to work. The only problem is that no matter what I put as the user input as to whether or not to repeat the program, it just goes right to the beginning. I cant exit the program. ive been searching around for the solution, but no cigar. I should mention that I dont have that much experience in programming. But i will try to understand what I did wrong. Any help is good help

```
    int main()
    {
        //variables
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
        double x1;
        double x2;
        double discriminant;
        char exeAgain='n';

        do
        {
          cout<<"Please enter a value for A, B, and C to be used in the quadratic formula (and then press 'enter'): "<<endl;
          cin>>a>>b>>c; //gets the values for A, B, and C

            //the equations for the quadratic formula
           discriminant=(b*b-(4*a*c));
           x1= (-1*b + (sqrt(discriminant)))/(2*a);
           x2= (-1*b - (sqrt(discriminant)))/(2*a);

            if(discriminant>0) //if inside the sqrt is more than 0 (desired)
            {
                cout<<"The roots of " <<a<< "x^2 + " <<b<< "x + " <<c<< " is/are: " <<endl;
                cout<<x1<<" and "<<x2<<endl;
            }

            else if(discriminant==0) //if inside the sqrt is 0
            {
                cout<<"The roots of " <<a<< "x^2 + " <<b<< "x + " <<c<< " is " <<endl;
                cout<<x1<<endl;
            }

            else //the discriminant is less than 0 (leads to complex roots)
            {
                discriminant = -1 * discriminant; //used to change the discriminant to a positive # 
                cout<<"The roots of " <<a<< "x^2 + " <<b<< "x + " <<c<< " is/are: " <<endl;
                cout<<"("<<(-1*b)<<" + "<<sqrt(discriminant)<<"i)/"<<2*a<<" and ("<<(-1*b)<<" - "<<sqrt(discriminant)<<"i)/"<<2*a<<endl;

            } 
               cout<<"Would you like to execute this program again? Type in Y or y for yes, or any other letter to quit the program: ";
               cin>>exeAgain;

     } while(exeAgain == 'y' || exeAgain == 'Y');
         return 0;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are doing the OR `||` check. Your second condition will always evaluate to true.

change it to:

```
while(exeAgain == 'y' || exeAgain == 'Y');
```

Comment: i changed that part but it still does the same as before. y or n just ends up going right to the beginning.

Comment: You changed it to `==` or still using `!=`?? Could you post your change!

Comment: My apologies. I did not change it from != to == . I did now and it works just how I wanted to. Thanks for your help. I will also update the code above. Once again, THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `exeAgain != 'y' || exeAgain != 'Y'`.

The current expression `exeAgain != 'y' || 'Y'` means "`exeAgain` is different from `'y'` or `'Y'` is not zero. As `'Y'` is a literal constant different from zero, the loop always repeat.

Comment: I incorporated your answer, but it still repeats the loop. no matter what letter I type (y or n) it just goes back to the beginning.

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry for the confusion. I mistyped the comparison. It should always have been `==` instead of `!=`. But the other answer posted at the same time have already answered it right.